# Binomial division

Tags: binomial-coefficients, divisibility

Looks very easy, but I can't make it:

$s \geq 2$ and $w \geq 2$ are prime numbers. $k$ is a natural number and $k \leq \min \{s,w \}$

Show that $\binom{s+w}{k}-\binom{w}{k} - \binom{s}{k}$ can be divided by $sw$.

Comment: Interesting question! However, I think we need to require that $k\leq s,w$; the only convention I'm aware of is $\binom{n}{k}=0$ when $k>n$, and it is easy to construct counterexamples to the claim in this scenario (for example $k=s+w$).

Comment: @Spore234 A small note: When you say $s,w$ are primes, there is no need to also mention they are $\geq 2$, since all primes are $\geq 2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Zev mentions, we do need some bounds on $k$.  We have your statement for $0\leq k\leq \min(s,w)$.  Here I will prove it for $1\leq k\leq \min(s-1,w-1)$.  (The other cases are not much different)  The goal is to look at your expression modulo $s$ and modulo $w$ and show it is $0$ in both cases.

**Proof:**  Expanding the binomials we have  $$\frac{(s+w)(s+w-1)\cdots(s+w-k+1)}{k!}-\frac{s(s-1)\cdots (s-k+1)}{k!}-\frac{w(w-1)\cdots(w-k+1)}{k!}.$$ Then since $s,w$ are primes, $k!$ is invertible, so that modulo $s$ this is

$$\equiv \frac{(w)(w-1)\cdots(w-k+1)}{k!}-\frac{w(w-1)\cdots(w-k+1)}{k!}\equiv 0\pmod{s}.$$

Similarly for $w$.  Hence the original expression is divisible by both $s$ and $w$.

**Elaboration:**  Because $1\leq k<s$, $k!$ will be relatively prime to $s$ so that dividing by $k!$ makes "sense." Then we can write $\frac{1}{k!}\equiv a \pmod{s}$ for some integer $a$.  Using this, the term $$\frac{s(s-1)\cdots (s-k+1)}{k!}\equiv as(s-1)\cdots (s-k+1),$$ and must be divisible by $s$.  The fraction $$\frac{(s+w)(s+w-1)\cdots(s+w-k+1)}{k!}\equiv a(s+w)(s+w-1)\cdots(s+w-k+1)$$ $$\equiv a(w)(w-1)\cdots(w-k+1)\pmod{s}$$ since each $s$ is equivalent to zero.

Comment: thanks. It is becoming more clear, but can you elaborate the second step a bit. Expanding the binomials is clear, I've been this far myself. We did this in a statistics class, I'm not really a number theorist.

Comment: @spore234: I put an extra note in.  Tell me if there is anything else.

Comment: thanks for elaborating, but I still don't understand this step: $a(s+w)(s+w-1)\cdots(s+w-k+1) \equiv a(w)(w-1)\cdots(w-k+1)\pmod{s}$

Comment: @spore234:  Ok.  When we work $\pmod{s}$ we are looking at the remainder after division by $s$, so adding in an integer multiple of $s$ doesn't change anything.  Lets do two variables.  We have that $(a+s)(b)=ab+sb\equiv ab \pmod {s}$.  In the same way, $(a+s)(b+s)(c+s)\equiv (a)(b)(c)\pmod{s}$, and this generalizes to any number of variables as above.  Here is another way to look at it:  We are just trying to show that above quantity is divisible by $s$.  Well, if we split up $(s+w)$ the term with the $s$ is already divisible by $s$ so we don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** $\ $ Scale by $\rm\:k!\:$ then use $\rm\ f(0) = 0\ \Rightarrow\ x\:y\ |\ f(x+y) - f(x) - f(y)\:$ for $\rm\:f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]\:.$

Your problem is the special case is $\rm\ f(x) = x\ (x-1)\:\cdots\:(x-k+1)\:,\ \ x = s,\ y = w\:.$

Comment: Nice structural argument, which has the additional advantage of working when $s=w$.